# UILocalNotifications repeatInterval using NSWeekdayCalendarUnit

Tags: uilocalnotification

OK, so I have seen several posts that say you cannot set a `UILocalNotification` to repeat any more or less than a few given options (every minute/hour/day/week/month etc.).

However, none of those posts addressed what setting the `repeatInterval` property of `UILocalNotification` to `NSWeekdayCalendarUnit` would do.

I'm very new to all this NSDate and NSCalendar stuff, so I am sure I am missing something, but I have read over the documentation and, it sounds like you CAN use `NSWeekdayCalendarUnit` to make a `NSLocalNotification` repeat say, every Monday, Tuesday and Thursday if `NSWeekdayCalendarUnit` is set to 2,3,5.

> NSWeekdayCalendarUnit
>   Specifies the weekday unit.
>   The corresponding value is an int. Equal to kCFCalendarUnitWeekday. The weekday units are the numbers 1 through N (where for the Gregorian calendar N=7 and 1 is Sunday).

Is that not correct?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. I do it like this. The user can choose a scheme with a picker. And then the choice goes to the following method:

```
- (void)setOneLocalAlarmNotification: (NSDate *)firstFireDate withRepeat: (NSInteger)repeat {

UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (localNotif == nil)
    return;
localNotif.fireDate = firstFireDate;
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotif.repeatCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

switch(repeat) {
    case 0: 
        break ;
    case 1: 
        localNotif.repeatInterval = kCFCalendarUnitDay;
        break;
    case 2: 
        localNotif.repeatInterval = kCFCalendarUnitWeekday;
        break;
    default: 
        break;
}

// Notification details
localNotif.alertBody = @"Message?";
// Set the action button
localNotif.alertAction = @"Yes";

localNotif.soundName = @"glas.caf"; //UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

// Specify custom data for the notification
    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Alarm" forKey:@"type"];
   localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;

// Schedule the notification
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
[localNotif release]
}
```

Comment: If I am understanding this, when you pass a 1 for 'repeat' that sets the local notification to repeat everyday. If you pass a 2 for 'repeat' then it only repeats on weekdays (so Mon-Fri while excluding Sat and Sun). Or is it possible to set the value of 'kCFCalendarUnitWeekeday' to say, arbitrarily, 3 to have the local notification repeat every Tuesday.